# Как сделать уникальными строки и соединит другие столбцы строки в строку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть таблица, с названиями столбцов 'A','B','C'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю как сделать вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пыталась сделать df.pivot_table(values='В',index='А', columns='С'), но выдает ошибку.
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить данную проблему? Еще мысли есть что в итоге должен получиться словарь из списков, где будет {1: [1:a], [2:d].....
Скорее всего я запуталась очень сильно, и не понимаю что делать и как искать в интернете. Если кто-то поймет меня и направит на правильную мысль, буду очень благодарна!

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 0):

df.groupby(df.columns.difference(['B']).tolist())
.B.apply(pd.Series.unique).reset_index()

Нашла, спасибо всем. Но если есть у кого ещё идеи-делитесь)